# ext4 ACL support in Trusty

Tags: acl

Having problems with ACL in Trusty desktop version, I want to know if the acl mount option is really mandatory for an ext4 partition?

Since with or without this option, `setfacl` never complains support is missing, I wonder if setting the option when it is not mandatory anymore would cause issues?

Comment: I believe it depends on the file system and how it is configured. You can check with `tune2fs -l /dev/your_partition` If the file system supports acl (most do) and it is no enabled by default, then you would use fstab.

Comment: I recall a question here some days ago where the user had not used the `acl` option. `setfacl` didn't complain, but none of his ACLs actually had any effect until he remounted with the `acl` option.

Comment: It depends on the settings ubuntu uses (and version of ubuntu). Many distros have acl enabled by default. In the past, ubuntu had acl disabled, I am not sure of the current status, but tune2fs will show you.

Comment: Once removed acl option in fstab and I `mount -v -o remount /srv` and `tune2fs -l UUID=....` reports `Default mount options:  user_attr acl`, can I say acl support is ready for this mount point?

Comment: EDIT: just leaving in fstab `UUID=... /srv ext4 defaults 0 2`

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu Desktop 14.04 the `acl` option in `/etc/fstab` and `mount` command is superfluous, even when the option `defaults` is not specified.

Instead, the `noacl` option disables acl support